# .NET filename with # error - 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: c#, file, iis, .net-core

I am working on .NET Core 2.2 application (will be upgraded soon). There is a functionality to upload files on the server which can be accessed by other users via a link. Everything works pretty fine. There are checks to prevent files with certain characters including `#`. The only issue I am having is, client is insisting to allow `#` in filename. There are no issues when uploading such files, but it doesn't load via link. I get `Status Code: 404; Not Found` error. This was the issue in legacy site (ASP.NET WebForms) as well where it was showing `404 - File or directory not found.`.
The URL I get looks like this: `/_ClientData/NTTF/Announcements/61/Docs/invalid%20#%20test.pdf`

As a last option, I can allow this files and replace `#` with something else on server, but I am wondering if there is any way to make this work without manipulating filename.

Comment: Why does the url need to match the filename? You say `When file is uploaded, I save it on the server and return location url back to the editor.` Why not save it as a random filename and return that url? Why does it need to match it any way?

Comment: @mjwills manipulating the filename is my last option. I prefer to make it work with original filenames because we're migrating an existing site and there are few files with this issue that we need to support. (Client requirement!! It was developed by other company in past and this issue left uncaught - unfortunately). If there are no options, we'll just update the filenames to something else and make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an Razor page (or equivalent) that dynamically generates the "clickable link".

SUGGESTION: Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode) to explicitly generate the link, as you serve the page.

It should generate something like this:

- File Name: `invalid # test.pdf`
- HttpUtility.UrlEncode: `invalid%20%23%20test.pdf`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it generated different version than you posted.
So basically user posts an announcement, and have ability to upload files in the content editor. When file is uploaded, I save it on the server and return location url back to the editor. I updated the code to return encoded version of filename using `location = $"{baseUrl}\\{Path.Combine(docDirectory, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.FileName))}";` , but it generated `invalid+%23+test.pdf`. The one you posted in your answer works fine.

Comment: UPDATE: I tried to `Uri.EscapeUriString()` to encode whitespace, but `#` remained the problem. I also tried combination but didn't work because %20 was encoded again. `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Uri.EscapeUriString(file.FileName))` and `Uri.EscapeUriString(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(file.FileName))` apparently won't work for same reason.

Comment: `invalid+%23+test.pdf` This is not a good long term solution, but have you considered `string.Replace` the `+` to `%20` @Pirate?

Comment: @mjwills `invalid+%23+test.pdf` doesn't work. The only one that works is the one posted in the answer. I've not considered replacing `+` because `+` is allowed in the filename. I am trying avoid manipulating the original filename on server.

Comment: @Pirate Read my comment again. Since if you do what I suggest you should get the working filename.

Comment: @mjwills ok yeah, i see what you're saying. That helped. I was thinking that `+` are allowed in filename, so it will be updated too but since now I am using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`, it will be encoded and there will be `+` for spaces only.

Thank you so much, you saved my day!